# How do I switch the WPF UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to change to UserControl2 when pressed button in UserControl1 attatched to the MainWindow.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid>
            <local:A x:Name="a" Margin="0,0" Width="1200" /> <--UserControl1
            <local:B x:Name="b" Margin="0,0" Width="1200" /> <--UserControl2
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        this.Closed += this.WindowClosed;
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.a.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.b.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

If button clicked than

```
this.a.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; 
this.b.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put following code in your button click event

```
Window w = Window.GetWindow(this);
if(null != w)
{
    ((UserControl)w.FindName("a")).Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    ((UserControl)w.FindName("b")).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Correct! I want it! Thank you so much!!